# Github Actions problem with environment secrets using NextJS13 with Firebase

Tags: firebase, github-actions, next.js13

I am attempting to create a github workflow using nextJS13 and firebase, i am using .env.local on my development environment and already set-up on my github environments secrets. but after so many attempts it does seems to get the correct keys, i already delete and add it back again on github environments but still error on my github actions.

here is my .yml file

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x, 18.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Make envfile
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1
        with:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_authDomain: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_projectId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_storageBucket: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_messagingSenderId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_appId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPID }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_measurementId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENTID }}
          file_name: .env
          directory: ./
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
```

my config.ts

```
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_appId,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_measurementId,
};
```

and my github secrets

[image]

on my github actions log

[image]

Comment: Manage to solve my problem following the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028847/how-to-set-an-env-secret-in-github-action move the env to job level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by moving the env to job level, hope this will help anyone who encounter the same problem.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_authDomain: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTHDOMAIN }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_projectId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECTID }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_storageBucket: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGEBUCKET }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_messagingSenderId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_appId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_APPID }}
      NEXT_PUBLIC_measurementId: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENTID }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x, 18.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
```